# SFTP non-empty folder delete recursively

Tags: java, sftp

I tried JSCH for deleting non empty folder via SFTP, but it did not work.

This one works, but it is not free :( I am already past 30 days trial period. My company refuse to pay them for just deleting the folder via SFTP.

```
package com.test.cvsutil;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.jscape.inet.sftp.Sftp;
import com.jscape.inet.sftp.SftpException;
import com.jscape.inet.sftp.events.SftpAdapter;
import com.jscape.inet.ssh.util.SshParameters;

public class SFTPFileDeleter extends SftpAdapter {
     static String hostName = ServerProperties.getProperty("test.ftp.hostname");
     static String username = ServerProperties.getProperty("test.ftp.login");
     static String password = ServerProperties.getProperty("test.ftp.password");
     static String directory = ServerProperties.getProperty("test.ftp.directory");
    private static Sftp sftp;

    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SFTPFileDeleter.class);


    public static boolean deleteDir(List <String> path) throws SftpException {
        Boolean flag = false;
        log.info("------------------------ file(s) delete started ------------------------");
        sftp = new Sftp(new SshParameters(hostName, username, password));

        sftp.connect();
        sftp.setDir(directory);

        for (String eachOne : path) {
            if (!sftp.getDirListingAsString(eachOne).equals("")){
                log.info(" ------  Deleted Folder/Scenario Name: " + eachOne);
                //log.info(" ------  check file path: " + directory+eachOne);
                //System.out.println(directory+eachOne);
                sftp.deleteDir(directory+eachOne, true);
                flag = true;
            }
        }

        sftp.disconnect();
        log.info("------------------------ file(s) delete finished -----------------------");

        return flag;
    }

    // open connection to the remote server.
    public static void openConnection() throws SftpException {
        sftp.connect();
    }

    // disconnect from the remote server.
    public static void closeConnection() {
        sftp.disconnect();
    }
}
```

and this is the error I got, so `jscape sftp` will not work for me.

```
2014-11-29 09:00:04 ERROR MainEntry:47 - There was error and message is java.lang.RuntimeException: Your Secure FTP Factory license expired on Sun Nov 23 00:31:21 CST 2014. Please v
isit http://www.jscape.com to purchase a licensed copy.
2014-11-29 09:00:04 ERROR MainEntry:48 - There was error and stack-trace is [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@fdb00d
```

any help is much appreciated. Asking here if anybody know other libraries that does delete non-empty folder.

Comment: You can ask such questions over at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not just use jsch to recursively delete everything in the folder before trying to delete the folder? Get list of everything in the directory and iterate over them. Test each to see if it is a file or a directory. If it is a directory, make a recursive call to make it empty and delete it. If it is a file, just delete it.

Comment: @jiten-k what kind of answer are you looking for here? Questions looking for third-party, fully working software are off-topic here. The code that you posted apparently isn't working because your license for the JScape library is expired. You ought to be able to implement this in jsch, but you didn't provide any details about your jsch attempt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to delete the directory recursively. Thanks @Rob

here is the code that will help if anybody looking for it out there.

```
public static void deleteDirectory(ChannelSftp sftp, String oldestBackup) throws SftpException {
    if (isDir(sftp, oldestBackup)) {
        sftp.cd(oldestBackup);
        Vector < LsEntry > entries = sftp.ls(".");
        for (LsEntry entry: entries) {
            deleteDirectory(sftp, entry.getFilename());
        }
        sftp.cd("..");
        sftp.rmdir(oldestBackup);
    } else {
        sftp.rm(oldestBackup);
    }
}

private static boolean isDir(ChannelSftp sftp, String entry) throws SftpException {
    return sftp.stat(entry).isDir();
}
```

Comment: A **warning** to someone who wants to use this code snippet directly: `ChannelSftp#ls` method also lists parent directory and current directory. This code **must** be modified before you test it.